# Redirect sys.stderr to method of class instance?

Tags: python, stderr

In python, is it possible to redirect sys.stderr to the method of a class instance? Having tried and failed to use the standard logging module in conjunction with the multiprocessing module, I've resorted to writing my own, custom logger. While this may be a poor alternative, I only need basic logging capabilities and the endless serialization errors were driving me crazy. In short I'd like to do something like,

```
import sys
class TestClass():

    def test_method(msg):
        acquire threading lock and write to file

logger = TestClass()
sys.stderr = logger.test_method
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Any file-like object can be used as `stderr` -- it doesn't even need to be derived from `file` and mainly just needs a `write()` method. Essentially, you just need to name your `test_method` as `write` and assign `sys.stderr` to `logger` rather than `logger.test_method`. You may also want to implement `flush()`, possibly doing nothing.

```
class TestClass():

    def write(msg):
        # acquire threading lock and write to file

    def flush():
        pass

logger = TestClass()
sys.stderr = logger
```

You could also implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to make your class work as a context manager, especially if there is cleanup needed (e.g. restoring `stderr` to the usual file).

Comment: I tried running this code by replacing the ` # acquire threading lock` comment with `print(msg)`, but the code never terminates - it just keeps running. I've also tried appending `msg` to a list, and the same result occurs.